# getting 404 not found error while trying to do $.getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

I checked the link and it works perfectly. This is the error I am getting in the console:

> GET http://localhost:60789/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tel%20Aviv%2CIL&units=metric&APPID=the given number 404 (Not Found)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var getIP = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
    var openWeatherMap = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'

    $.getJSON(getIP).done(function(location) {
        $.getJSON(openWeatherMap, {
            q: location.regionName + "," + location.countryCode,
            units: 'metric',
            APPID: 'Here iam giving my appid'
        }).done(function (weather) {
                console.log(weather);                
            $('ul:first-child').html(weather.name + "," + weather.sys.country);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: That GET request clearly shows the issue... Someone is not using an absolute link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `http://` prefix on the `openWeatherMap` URL. Because of this the browser assumes the path you're providing is relative to the current URL, so prepends `http://localhost:60789/` to it - hence your 404.

To fix the problem, simply prepend `http://` to the URL to make it absolute:

```
var openWeatherMap = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
```